# python pandas: how to make the first part of a cell the column name, and the second part of a cell the column value

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have a `df`, below is a sample of the first row:

```
sample_df.to_dict()

{'Disease_and_concern_0': {1: 'skin irritation/allergies/damage+Moderate Concern'},
 'Disease_and_concern_1': {1: 'developmental/endocrine/reproductive effects+Some Concern'},
 'Disease_and_concern_2': {1: 'damage to vision+Some Concern'}}

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_df)
```

For each column, I would like to take the first part of the string before the **+**, and make it the column name. The second part of the string after the **+**, should be the cell value.

My desired output:

```
  skin irritation/allergies/damage developmental/endoctrine/reproductive effects damage to vision
0                 Moderate Concern                                  Some Concern     Some Concern
```

I think there is a simple solution for this, I've been trying to figure it out for some time but with no luck. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can try `str.split`:

```
df = sample_df.apply(lambda s: s.str.split('+').str[1])
df.columns = sample_df.iloc[0].str.split('+').str[0].tolist()
```

Alternatively you can `stack` the dataframe then `split` around delimiter `+` and use `unstack` to reshape:

```
s = sample_df.stack().str.split('+')
df = s.str[1].droplevel(1).to_frame().set_index(s.str[0], append=True)[0].unstack()
```

Result:

```
  skin irritation/allergies/damage developmental/endocrine/reproductive effects damage to vision
1                 Moderate Concern                                 Some Concern     Some Concern
```

Answer (score 1):

manipulate the dictionary directly

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = {
    "Disease_and_concern_0": {1: "skin irritation/allergies/damage+Moderate Concern"},
    "Disease_and_concern_1": {
        1: "developmental/endocrine/reproductive effects+Some Concern"
    },
    "Disease_and_concern_2": {1: "damage to vision+Some Concern"},
}

result = defaultdict(dict)
for key, value in data.items():
    for idx, d in value.items():
        col, v = d.split('+')
        result[idx][col] = v
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index')
```